# iOS Library for multiple architectures combined with slices

Tags: ios, slice, ios-library

I have a compiled iOS sdk. There is an include folder that contains the header files for the library. There is a lib folder, and inside are folders arm64, armv7, armv7s, and i386. Inside each of these folders is a lib.a file.
I have a sample app the uses this sdk, and the only way I know to run it is to add an absolute path in Library Search Paths to one of the lib.a files depending on what device I want to use. For example, if I want to run the sample app in the simulator, I add a path the the lib.a file in the i386 folder. If I want to run the app on an iPhone 5c, I change the path to use the armv7 folder.

My goal is to have one lib.a file that will work on all devices. I have heard about something called Slices, but I don't know where to start reading in order to combine these libraries for the different architectures. I do not have the source code for this sdk, only the headers and lib.a files.

What are the steps to combining this sdk into one library and then including it in my xcode project with a relative path?

Comment: Figured it out : lipo -create '.../sdk_ios/lib/arm64/lib.a' '.../sdk_ios/lib/armv7/lib.a' '.../sdk_ios/lib/armv7s/lib.a' '.../sdk_ios/lib/i386/lib.a' -output 'lib.a'